# What is the best solution for Wordpress or Marketo to Salesforce Integration?

Tags: community

What is the best solution for integrating with Wordpress and Salesforce? Or Wordpress and Marketo then supplying information to CRM Salesforce?

Comment: What are you trying to integrate? More specific integration description can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marketo developer evangelist here. I would recommend taking a look at [Hoosh Marketing's Wordpress/Marketo integration](http://launchpoint.marketo.com/hoosh-marketing/1181-wordpress-integration-for-marketo/). This integration allows you to submit data from a Wordpress form directly into Marketo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar position. I have a Wordpress site but have to get Marketo form(s) working with it ... but Marketo forms are very clunky and near impossibly to customize/style very well. Here's what I've rounded up so far.

- [Hoosh Wordpress/Marketo Integration](http://product.hooshmarketing.com.au/wordpress-marketo-integration-pricing-reveal/) ... mentioned by MurtzaM / paid plugin ($86/mo?)
- [OptinMonster](https://wordpress.org/plugins/optinmonster/) ... paid plugin ($9/mo+)
- [Forms by CaptainForm](https://wordpress.org/plugins/captainform/) ... yet another paid plugin ($195/yr for Marketo compat)
- [Marketo Gravity Forms addon](https://wordpress.org/plugins/marketo/) ... plugin free but [Gravity Forms](https://www.gravityforms.com) a paid plugin ($59/yr +)
- [Marketo Forms and Tracking](https://wordpress.org/plugins/marketo-forms-and-tracking/) ... free but not updated > 2 yrs and [not clear how to use](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-can-i-find-the-information-to-fill-in-the-fields-within-the-options-page/?replies=4)
- [Ultimate Marketo Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-marketo-forms/) ... a pro version plugin but free? The setup/docs looks legit but after getting the REST/API stuff setup it's not working so ... TBD if this one works or not.

PS: If anyone finds a magic (ideally free) option that "just works" please chime in ... I'm still trying to find the best solution.